# Browser freezes using beforeEach

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to set some routes that users can and can't access in my application, but sometimes my browser freezes and it doesn't give me any error messages, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

In the first IF, I'm checking if the route needs auth to be true to access, if it's false, I send user to login page. Then I check the group user is in, if it fails, redirect to root page "/". And if none of these IFs statements is true, I just redirect to the page user wants to navigate to.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

      const isAuth = localStorage.getItem("auth");
      const userGroupRaw = localStorage.getItem("userData");
      const accessGroup = to.meta.group;
      let userGroup;
      if (userGroupRaw) {
        userGroup = JSON.parse(userGroupRaw).id_access;
      }
    
      if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        console.log("if1");
        if (isAuth === "false") {
          next({ path: "/login" });
        }
        if (
          (accessGroup === 1 && (userGroup === 3 || userGroup === 4)) ||
          !userGroup
        ) {
          next({ path: "/" });
        }
    
        next();
      }
    
      next();
    });
    export default router;
```

Comment: The common reason for freezing: Infinite loops.

Comment: try using `return next()` instead of just `next()`

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#optional-third-argument-next) say "you must call `next` exactly once" <sup>1</sup>. If the first `if` is true, it's called twice. If the second or third `if`s are true, it gets called three times.

You might need to return inside the `if`s to avoid that. Or use `else` statements.

**Update** to add examples:

Here's an example using `else` (preferable if you're on v3.x):

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isAuth = localStorage.getItem("auth");
  const userGroupRaw = localStorage.getItem("userData");
  const accessGroup = to.meta.group;
  let userGroup;
  if (userGroupRaw) {
    userGroup = JSON.parse(userGroupRaw).id_access;
  }

  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    console.log("if1");
    if (isAuth === "false") {
      next({ path: "/login" });
    } else if (
      (accessGroup === 1 && (userGroup === 3 || userGroup === 4)) ||
      !userGroup
    ) {
      next({ path: "/" });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
export default router;
```

---

1: For the current version (v4.x), the docs also say that `next` was supposed to be removed, [according to this RFC](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0037-router-return-guards.md). I don't see a deprecation warning, but using it is discouraged.

In that case, this is a better solution for the current version:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  const isAuth = localStorage.getItem("auth");
  const userGroupRaw = localStorage.getItem("userData");
  const accessGroup = to.meta.group;
  let userGroup;
  if (userGroupRaw) {
    userGroup = JSON.parse(userGroupRaw).id_access;
  }

  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    console.log("if1")
    if (isAuth === "false") {
      return { path: "/login" };
    }
    
    if (
      (accessGroup === 1 && (userGroup === 3 || userGroup === 4)) ||
      !userGroup
    ) {
      return { path: "/" };
    }
  }
});
export default router;
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're not using 'else' statements, you're calling `next()` multiple times and hitting an infinite loop (as mentioned in the comments).

You can `return` instead to stop the code at that point.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  const isAuth = localStorage.getItem("auth");
  const userGroupRaw = localStorage.getItem("userData");
  const accessGroup = to.meta.group;
  let userGroup;
  if (userGroupRaw) {
    userGroup = JSON.parse(userGroupRaw).id_access;
  }

  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (isAuth === "false") {
        return next({
            path: "/login"
        }); 
    }
    if (
        (accessGroup === 1 && (userGroup === 3 || userGroup === 4)) ||
        !userGroup
    ) {
        return next({
            path: "/"
        });
    }
    // next(); - this is not needed as the preceding next always gets called.
  }
  next();
})

export default router;
```

Comment: In this case `else` would be preferable. `return next` suggests that it returns something useful, while in fact it's not